# .htaccess not working - Removing .php File Extensions from URLs

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm having trouble removing the .php file extensions from URLs using the .htaccess file.

Previously, all pages were HTML and I had successfully rewritten URLs to drop the .html extensions, but it just doesn't seem to be working for .php — I'm just getting 404 errors.

**.htaccess Contents**

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.brianglassmandesign.com/404.php

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^brianglassmandesign.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.brianglassmandesign.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]

# Remove file extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [L]
```

Comment: The last line is matching on `.*` which includes the extension. What happens when you replace that with something that matches up to, but not including, the extension? Like `RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]`

Comment: @Anton, if the OP requests `/something`, surely it should resolve to `/something.php` anyway? The only change (seemingly) the OP made was from `.html` to `.php`...

Comment: You're right @MikeRockett, it shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason as to why the files are not being picked up, giving consideration to the fact that the only change you made was the extension. As such, I recommend that you double-check to see if the file being requested actually exists, and has been renamed from the old `.html` equivalent.

The only `.htaccess` suggestion I can offer that is an alternative to what you have is the following:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule (.+) $1.php [L]
```

This means that the rewrite will only occur if the file exists. So, if you request `/something` and `/something.php` exists on the file-system, then it will be served accordingly.

Failing which, you'll need to check the relevant logs to determine what the problem may be.

Comment: You've solved the riddle, my friend.After creating /something and updating .htaccess with your modifications — everything seems to be working properly. Thank you!

Comment: Great! Please accept this answer for the benefit of others.